# dynamic allocation of class object without constructor

Tags: c++

How can I dynamically allocate a class  object that has no defined constructor?

I tried:

```
A * newPtr = new A();
```

But it's giving me some kind of memory leak on gdb.

Cheers!

Comment: After _A * newPtr = new A();_ you must free memory by _delete newPtr_

Comment: There are several unrelated concerns mentioned in this question. It's hard to understand what exactly you are asking. If `A` has *no* constructor it's not possible to `new` one. Though the compile can often generate constructors for you. If gdb complains about a memory leak, it's likely because you didn't `delete newPtr;` or `A` has raw owning pointers. If that's the case consider using smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: Every class has a constructor (even if deleted). Please provide a [mcve] to better explain what you're trying to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: if your class has no (public?) constructor then it doesnt matter if you want to dynamically allocate or use automatic storage, you simply cannot. Seems like you are mixing different things. Without a constructor `new A();` cannot work

Answer (score 4):

If there's no defined constructor and standard rules allow it then you get a *implicitly-declared* [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), otherwise your code wouldn't compile at all.

So if you are not defining any constructor and your code compiles then for sure a default one is declared and defined (so you actually have a constructor).

You get a leak because you need to `delete` the pointer to free its memory from the heap.